# PHP JSON wrong value

Tags: php, json

**JSON Data**

```
{ 
   "data":{ 
      "count":1,
      "orders":[ 
         { 
            "voucher_platform":0,
            "voucher":0.00,
            "order_number":270269205514864,
            "voucher_seller":0,
            "created_at":"2019-12-15 18:03:44 +0800",
            "gift_option":false,
            "statuses":[ 
               "delivered"
            ],
            "address_billing":{ 
               "last_name":"",
               "address5":"Sample",
               "address4":"Sample",
               "first_name":"Sample name"
            },
            "extra_attributes":"",
            "order_id":270269205514864,
            "gift_message":"",
            "remarks":"",
            "address_shipping":{ 
               "country":"",
               "address3":"",
               "address2":"",
               "city":"",
               "phone":"",
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "code":"0",
   "request_id":"0b0da12615764049458554660"
}
```

I got an issue with the value of `order_number`, instead of getting the correct value which is `270269205514864` the result I'm getting is `2.7087557899228E+14`.

I think the problem is somewhat related to string and numeric value but I don't know how can I fix it.

here's some of my code related to decoding the json data.

```
...
$data = ... //assuming the json is already initialized

$data = json_decode($data, true); //decode the json
$OrderNumber = $data['data']['orders'][0]["order_number"]; //get order number
$CustomerName = $data['data']['orders'][0]["address_billing"]["first_name"]; //get name

echo $OrderNumber;
echo '<br/>';
echo $CustomerName;
echo '<br/>';
echo 'JSON DATA:';
die($data);
```

Anyway, the JSON is from another server so I won't be able to edit them. I only receive the JSON.

Comment: PHP handles this JSON without problems and without errors: https://3v4l.org/nBDi7 And `echo $OrderNumber` displays what it is expected to display: https://3v4l.org/9aVQK.

Comment: But if you run the code on PHP 5 on Windows, the value of `$OrderNumber` is too large for an integer (32 bits), it is stored as float and the behaviour you described appears. It can be corrected by setting a larger value for [`precision`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision). Either way, you better use a string for `order_number`. It looks like a number but none of the usual operations we do with numbers (addition, subtraction, multiplication, comparison etc) makes sense for it.

Comment: Add a `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` to see what the max value of an int is on your system. It'll be probably less than the value you're trying to fetch.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - I have `2147483647`.

Comment: @axiac - The JSON is from another server and I don't have access to it. I only received the JSON.

Comment: You still can do the conversion from number to string in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is converting your number into scientific notation. You can use the [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function to convert it to control how it is displayed.

In your case, assuming `order_number` is always a *positive integer* that should not have any *thousands separator*, you would need to change the default behavior of `number_format()`. Therefore, here is what I would do

```
// Get the order number
$OrderNumber = $data['data']['orders'][0]["order_number"];

// Make sure it is formatted properly
$OrderNumber = number_format($OrderNumber, 0, '.', ''); // Notice that the last parameter is set to empty string, to override the default and make sure there is no thousands separator
```

Please note, that this would result in `order_number` being a *number*. If you would like to deal with `order_number` as a *string*, then you should add the following line of code that uses [`strval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php)

```
$OrderNumberAsString = strval($OrderNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

`2.7087557899228E+14` is equivalent to `270269205514864`. 2.7087557899228E+14 is in scientific notation.

To get into original or normal form use: `number_format($number, 6)`, where 6 is the leading number length after the decimal.

```
$OrderNumber = number_format($data['data']['orders'][0]["order_number"], 6);
```